# Road bike tyre size for a mountain bike

Tags: road-bike, tire

The mountain bike I've restored has spent all its time riding roads. I'd love a road bike but funds aren't up to it yet,
so I was thinking about putting a pair of road bike tyres on and swapping with the mountain bike tyres when needed. 
I'm running 26x1.95 at the moment, and I'm wondering if I would benefit from a different size for the road. 
I'm assuming the 1.95 refers to the width of the tyre.

Comment: A 26x1.95 tire would be fine. You just need a 26x(some number in decimal) tire which ideally isn't too wide or narrow for your rim + frame. I'd look at 26x1.7-1.9.

Comment: You want to look for a smoother, non-knobbly tread for road usage, and to lock out any suspension.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are a pair of "slicks" for your mountain bike.  They come in a number of sizes for 26" wheels.  Batman suggests looking for a set between 1.7 - 1.9"  That is a good suggestion since you will be able to use the same tubes are are in your 1.95 mtb tires.

If you are willing to get a new set of tubes with those tires, I would suggest looking for 26 x 1.25 - 1.5" slicks.  It is a matter of preference, but I find them to be a bit quicker and responsive if you are willing to run the associated higher pressure.  If you commute has lots of curb jumping, pot holes, or broke pavement 1.75s may be my choice...

My experience is that 1.95 slicks really dont offer much over a fast rolling knobby tire.

Comment: Which one of these would be ok,if any. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/291861357505

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/111396137017

Comment: Martin, either look good... the first has a bit more inverted tread perhaps better on dirt roads... the second maybe a bit faster on pavement.

Comment: After lots of reading I changed my mind and went with 26x1.50's... reason being all roads around hear are country roads, very little smooth tarmac.,mostly rough. Also the 150's would provide a little more comfort and better for the occasional of road. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/262400242052